# I am facing the persistent "405 Method Not Allowed"" on a MVC PHPMailer with an environment and my routes were wrong

Tags: php, model-view-controller, phpmailer

I am facing the persistent **“405 Method Not Allowed”"** on a MVC PHPMailer within an environment.

I spent more than 10 hours, trying to fix the bug. I have been searching this case at Stack Overflow, but no luck. I assumed it was some PHPMailer config in the files `Mail.php` and `.env`, but all the config are correct. It also can the other files `App/routes.php` or `public/index.php`.

- `root/composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "lucas/simple-mvc",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Lucas Ayabe",
            "email": "lucas.akira@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "App/",
            "Core\\": "Core/"
        },
        "files": [
            "App/Helpers/view.php",
            "App/Helpers/partial.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "nikic/fast-route": "^1.3",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.2",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.1",
        "league/oauth2-google": "^3.0",
        "psr/log": "^1.1"
    }
}
```

- `root/.env`:

```
MAIL_HOST="br726.hostgator.com.br"
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USER="sacc@thproducoes.com"
MAIL_PASSWORD="mypassword"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Thiago Silva"
MAIL_FROM_EMAIL="sacc@thproducoes.com"
```

- `root/App/Helpers/Mail.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use Exception;
use stdClass;

class Mail
{
    private PHPMailer $mail;
    private stdClass $data;
    private Exception $error;

    public function __construct(string $lang = "br")
    {
        $this->mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $this->data = new stdClass();
        
        $this->mail->isSMTP();
        $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $this->mail->Host = $_ENV["MAIL_HOST"];
        $this->mail->Port = $_ENV["MAIL_PORT"];
        $this->mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
        $this->mail->Username = $_ENV['MAIL_USER'];
        $this->mail->Password = $_ENV['MAIL_PASSWORD'];

        $this->mail->isHTML(true);
        $this->mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
        $this->mail->setLanguage($lang);
    }

    public function add(
        string $subject,
        string $body,
        string $recipientName,
        string $recipientEmail
    ): self 
    {
        $this->data->subject = $subject;
        $this->data->body = $body;
        $this->data->recipientName = $recipientName;
        $this->data->recipientEmail = $recipientEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    public function attach(string $path, string $filename): self
    {
        $this->data->attach[$path] = $filename;
        return $this;
    }

    public function send(string $fromName = "", string $fromEmail = ""): bool
    {
        $fromName = $fromName !== "" ? $fromName : $_ENV['MAIL_FROM_NAME'];
        $fromEmail = $fromEmail !== "" ? $fromEmail : $_ENV['MAIL_FROM_EMAIL'];

        try {
            $this->mail->Subject = $this->data->subject;
            $this->mail->msgHTML($this->data->body);
            $this->mail->addAddress("sac@thproducoes.com");
            $this->mail->addAddress($this->data->recipientEmail, $this->data->recipientName);

            $this->mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);

            if (!empty($this->data->attach)) 
            {
                foreach ($this->data->attach as $path => $name) 
                {
                    $this->mail->addAttachment($path, $name);
                }
            }

            $this->mail->send();
            return true;
        } 
        
        catch (\Exception $exception) 
        {
            $this->error = $exception;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getError(): ?Exception
    {
        return $this->error;
    }
}
```

- `root/App/Views/mail.php`:

```
<?= partial("templates/header.php") ?>
<form action="mail" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="message">Mensagem</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
<?= partial("templates/footer.php")
?>
```

- `root/App/routes.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Source\routes;

use App\Controllers\MailController;
use App\Controllers\PagesController;
use FastRoute\RouteCollector;

return function (RouteCollector $routes) 
{
        $routes->get('/', [PagesController::class => "index"]);
        $routes->get('/mail', [MailController::class => "index"]);
        $routes->get('/send', [MailController::class => "send"]);
};
```

- `root/Core/App.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Core;

use FastRoute\Dispatcher as Dispatcher;

class App
{
    private Dispatcher $dispatcher;

    public function __construct(Dispatcher $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        // Fetch method and URI from somewhere
        $httpMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        $uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

        $routeInfo = $this->dispatcher->dispatch($httpMethod, $uri);

        switch ($routeInfo[0]) {
            case Dispatcher::NOT_FOUND:
                echo 'NOT FOUND';
                break;
            case Dispatcher::METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED:
                $allowedMethods = $routeInfo[1];
                echo '405 Method Not Allowed';
                break;
            case Dispatcher::FOUND:
                $controller = array_key_first($routeInfo[1]);
                $action = end($routeInfo[1]);

                (new $controller())->$action($routeInfo[2]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

- `root/Core/Controller.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Core;

abstract class Controller
{
    public function redirect(string $route)
    {
        header("Location: {$_ENV['BASE_URL']}/$route");
        exit();
    }
}
```

- `root/Core/View.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Core;

class View
{
    private array $vars = [];
    private const FORBIDDEN_VAR = "viewTemplaFile";

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->vars[$name];
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if ($name === self::FORBIDDEN_VAR) {
            throw new \Exception(
                "Cannot bind variable named '" . self::FORBIDDEN_VAR . "'"
            );
        }

        $this->vars[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function load(string $viewTemplateFile)
    {
        if (array_key_exists(self::FORBIDDEN_VAR, $this->vars)) {
            throw new \Exception(
                "Cannot bind variable named '" . self::FORBIDDEN_VAR . "'"
            );
        }

        extract($this->vars);
        ob_start();
        include __DIR__ . "/../App/Views/$viewTemplateFile";
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    public function render(string $viewTemplateFile)
    {
        echo $this->load($viewTemplateFile);
    }
}
```

- `root/public/index.php`:

```
<?php
use Core\App;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = \Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__ . '/../');
$dotenv->load();

$routes = require __DIR__ . "/../App/routes.php";

$app = new App(FastRoute\simpleDispatcher($routes));
$app->run();
```

And `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Are you deliberately using PHP `$_ENV` variables? This seems unusual. You should check your ENV variables are accesssible, and valid.

Comment: Also why have you not tried to use the PHPMailer debug `$this->mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` (or similar 1-5 level.)

Comment: `SMTPSecure` really, **really** should be TLS not SSL. SSL ceased many years ago. (I don't know how PHPMailer handles this common misconception that TLS and SSL are the same thing)

Comment: I also tested TLS, but it gave the same method, @Martin.

Comment: Do you have any details in your PHP Error Logs?

Comment: I ran the command `$this->mail->SMTPDebug = 3` (also `5`), but no errors appeared.

Comment: ok, so what about your $_ENV details? are they all correct and set ?

Comment: Yes, `$_ENV` details are correct. Check the `root/.env` above. I use `phpdotenv` and it is based on `header("Location: {$_ENV['BASE_URL']}/$route");`. I changed to TLS and inserted the SMTPDebug, but no errors appeared.

Comment: **The server MUST generate an Allow header field in a 405 response containing a list of the target resource's currently supported methods.** . So what are the allowed and supported alternative methods?

Comment: You will need to dig into your Server Error Logs; probably your Apache error logs to exactly find out why it returns HTTP 405. We can't help you here, it's going to be specific to your system, there are far too many possibilities it *might* be.

Comment: My classmate developed it, using XAMPP, but I use WSL. I do not have Apache installed on WSL. 

It seemed that the problems are `$routes->get('/mail', [MailController::class => "index"])` because of `<form action="mail" method="post">`. I replaced for `$routes->post`, but the SMTP failed with both SSL and TLS. Maybe Apache is not installed?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHPMailer, which has no effect on http. For the record, `SMTPSecure` mode names are `ssl` for implicit TLS (SMTPS), and `tls` for explicit TLS (SMTP+STARTTLS). SMTPS was deprecated for over 20 years, but has effectively been undeprecated recently, as implicit TLS has some security advantages. It’s got little to do with old SSL.